# How to split Text and Numbers using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV containing a 100000 columns with data like this:

```
CPUUtilization  OK  - 7.192  Percent
CPUUtilization  OK  - 1.140  Percent
CPUUtilization  OK  - 5.369  Percent
```

I need to omit all the text in it cpu uti..... and I only need the 7.192, 1.140 etc value get replaced and stored in that respective columns.

Please suggest a way to easily do this using awk, I'm new to awk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are the replacement values are coming from?  Are you mixing rows and columns?  100,000 columns seems excessive.

Comment: can you explain more about your question and provide expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the numerical column:

`awk '{print $4}' data.csv`

the default field separator is space, and you need to print out 4th field

Comment: Thank you . Ill give out my exact scenario